# Error when show media element to play audio streaming

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-streaming, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement to play an audio by streaming it through the server.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement
                            x:Name="questionMedia"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Margin="20,5,0,10"
                            Width="300"
                            Height="55"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                            AutoPlay="False"
                            Visibility="Visible">
                            <MediaElement.TransportControls>
                                <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True" IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"/>
                            </MediaElement.TransportControls>
                        </MediaElement>
```

Code:

```
string audioURL = "https://ujian.study.id/uploads/questions/audio/553.mp3";
                                questionMedia.Source = new Uri(audioURL);
```

I'm having a problem where the app keeps exiting and the error message below appears:
[image: error]

If I don't set the width and height of the mediaelement, then the error doesn't occur, but the audio won't play because I set `AutoPlay = false`.
How to handle it?

Comment: I tested your code and there is no error. Where did you put this code `QuestionMedia.Source = new Uri(audioURL)` ? Or can you reproduce the same problem in a blank UWP project?